# PDF::Create incorrectly converts french accented characters

Tags: perl, pdf, character-encoding

My Perl program can successfully convert english text to pdf using the PDF::Create module.  However, french accented characters do not display correctly in the PDF file.

Here is a line from the plain text file containing french characters:

> VÉRIFIER DÉCLARATION DE DROITS-FORMALITÉS

Here is what the same line looks like in the PDF file:

> VÃ‰RIFIER DÃ‰CLARATION DE DROITS-FORMALITÃ‰S

Here is the relevant code:

```
$page = $pdf->new_page('MediaBox' => [0,0,$pdfWidth,$pdfHeight]);
$font1 = $pdf->font('Subtype'=>'Type1',Encoding'=>'WinAnsiEncoding','BaseFont'=>'Courier');
$page->string($font1, $fontSize, $leftMarg, $yCoord, $pdfLine);
```

where $pdfLine contains the plain text.

The program reads in a file with this content:

> azAZàâäçèéê
>
> ÉTAT DES DEMANDES INACTIVES - OPÉRATION DES BREVETS
>
> TÂCHE
>
> VÉRIFIER DÉCLARATION DE DROITS-FORMALITÉS
>
> VÉRIFIER LISTAGE DES SÉQUENCE-FORMALITÉS

Comment: Where did the text in `$pdfLine` come from? Is it in your source code or do you read it from somewhere?

Comment: Please provide the result of `sprintf("%vX", $pdfLine)`

Comment: Human readable text line:
`A6        VÉRIFIER DÉCLARATION DE DROITS-FORMALITÉS                         0           0           0           0           1`

sprint formatted line:
`41.36.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.56.C9.52.49.46.49.45.52.20.44.C9.43.4C.41.52.41.54.49.4F.4E.20.44.45.20.44.52.4F.49.54.53.2D.46.4F.52.4D.41.4C.49.54.C9.53.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.30.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.30.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.30.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.30.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.31.A`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `$pdfLine` is UTF-8 encoded. You would want to decode it into unicode code points before writing it to the PDF.

```
use Encode 'decode';
$page->string($font1, $fontSize, $leftMarg, $yCoord, decode("UTF-8",$pdfLine));
```

You could also handle decoding at the input filehandle with an encoding layer:

```
open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', "file/that/contains/the/plain.txt";
...
$pdfLine = <$fh>;
...
$page->string($font1, $fontSize, $leftMarg, $yCoord, $pdfLine);
```

Comment: Without success I tried your first suggestion.  The PDF text now looks like: `Vï¿½RIFIER Dï¿½CLARATION DE DROITS-FORMALITï¿½S`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by installing an old version of PDF::Create.  I was running version 1.42 and I installed version 1.31.  French accented characters display fine using version 1.31.  So, somewhere between 1.31 and 1.42 the conversion of accented characters was broken.